# REQUEST_URI exact match modsecurity

Tags: mod-security

I need deny a portion of an url with modsecurity , example:

index.php?page_num=users

I have implemented this rule:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "/index\.php\?page_num=users" "id:10000100,phase:1,t:lowercase,deny,msg:'UsersDeny'"
```

It works for the URI "index.php?page_num=users" , but it also deny any characters after the users string, example:

```
index.php?page_num=userssadasd
```

How can i deny the exact URI " *index.php?page_num=users " ?

Comment: What is the rule going to accomplish? Seems odd to deny `?page=users` but not `?padding=&page=users`..

Answer (score 1):

Without explicit operator the engine uses the `@rx`. There are two possible ways to solve this problem:

- use the anchored pattern for regex, eg `REQUEST_URI "^/index\.php\?page_num=users$"`
- use the `@streq` operator: `REQUEST_URI "@streq /index.php?page_num=users"`